# Multidimensional Array + CSV Export

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have an issue with an export script im trying to write...

1. I create a multidimensional array

   while($row = $insert_row->fetch_assoc()) {

   ```
       foreach ($selectArray as $value) {
           $userData = $row[$value];
           $userDataArray[] = $userData;
       }
       $userArray[] = $userDataArray;
       unset($userDataArray);
   }
   ```
2. Now I want to create the CSV File

   $sendfilename = "export" . ".csv";
       $filename = "file" . ".csv";
       $delimiter = ';';
       $enclosure = '"';
       $encloseAll = true;
       $nullToMysqlNull = false;
       $delimiter_esc = preg_quote($delimiter, '/');
       $enclosure_esc = preg_quote($enclosure, '/');

   ```
   $fp = fopen($filename, 'wb');

   if ($fp)
   {
       foreach ($userArray as $users) {
           foreach ($users as $fields) {
               fputcsv($fp, $fields,";",'"');
           }
       }
   }
   fclose($fp);
   readfile($filename);
   ```

Im getting the error "fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given"

Any solution?

Comment: Try `var_dump($fields)` to see what you are getting . I believe you are getting this as a string.

Comment: Its returning string(1) "0"
string(1) "1"
string(0) ""
string(3) "adf"

Comment: fixed... went a level to deep on fput... my stupid fault!

Comment: Great. Congrats. !! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Already fixed, I went one level to deep on fput...